# How to check if a secret variable is empty in if conditional Github Actions

Tags: github-actions

### Context

I want to check in my workflow if a secret is present or not before executing a job.

Something like this:

```
publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID != ''
    steps:
      [ ... ]
```

However, I've got an error like this when using this expression:

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/release.yml (Line: 11, Col: 9): Unrecognized named-value: 'secrets'...
```

### What I tried

I tried to wrote the expression another way:

```
if: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID != '' }}
```

```
if: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }} != ''
```

### Question

**How to achieve what I want in a Github Actions workflow?**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The Github Action interpreter currently doesn't identify the `secrets` key word when used in an `if` conditional expression. Therefore, you can't use the `secrets.VARIABLE` syntax there.

Instead, use the environment to carry a result of a secret check and then use an `if` conditional upon the non-secret result.

**job.step Example:**

```yaml
job:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
    - name: Check for Secret availability
      id: secret-check
      # perform secret check & put boolean result as an output
      shell: bash
      run: |
        if [ "${{ secrets.MY_KEY }}" != '' ]; then
          echo "available=true" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT;
        else
          echo "available=false" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT;
        fi

    - name: Check Inadequate Permissions
      if: ${{ steps.secret-check.outputs.available != 'true' }}
      # provide feedback for likely problem, note dependabot cannot access
      # secrets by default. Secondly, this step forces job failure due to
      # missing secret via `exit 1`
      shell: bash
      run: |
        if [ "${{ github.actor }}" == "dependabot[bot]" ]; then
          echo >&2 "Unable to access secrets as unprivileged dependabot.";
        else
          echo >&2 "Inadequate Permissions or missing secret value";
        fi
        exit 1

    - name: Execute Step requiring secret
      # If you didn't abort step above, then use this conditional
      # if: ${{ steps.secret-check.outputs.available == 'true' }}
      shell: bash
      # Key will be blocked out in log output but will be not empty
      run: |
        echo "This command is executed with non-empty key: \
          ${{ secrets.MY_KEY }}"
```

If you need to do this at the job level, create a separate `check-secret` job to validate the secrets and then share the result as a defined output.

**Workflow Context Level Example:**

```yaml
jobs:

  check-secret:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      my-key-exists: ${{ steps.my-key-check.outputs.defined }}
    steps:
      - name: Check for Secret availability
        id: my-key-check
        # perform secret check & put boolean result as an output
        shell: bash
        run: |
          if [ "${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}" != '' ]; then
            echo "defined=true" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT;
          else
            echo "defined=false" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT;
          fi

  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [check-secret]
    if: needs.check-secret.outputs.my-key-exists == 'true'
    steps:
      - run: echo "This command is executed if AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID secret IS NOT empty"

  job2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [check-secret]
    if: needs.check-secret.outputs.my-key-exists != 'true'
    steps:
      - run: echo "This command is executed if AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID secret IS empty"
```

Comment: why do you wrap it in double-quotes? I've had to remove them myself to not get a syntax error in my workflow

Comment: It may have changed since the answer has been posted. I'll make some tests.

Comment: thing is, in my workflow I already had some `if: foo && bar` so if I changed it to `if: "${{ env.MY_KEY != '' }}" && foo && bar`, it gave me syntax error, so I had to remove double-quotes to leave it as `if: ${{ env.MY_KEY != '' }} && foo && bar`, however, I just realised that the latter works syntactically but doesn't work to detect the emptiness of the secret

Comment: DO NOT ADD the secret to the ENV. This defeats the entire purpose of the secrets context.  The environment is carried across all steps in a job.  Only use the `check-secret` example. Separately I think the job level is too high and should just be done at the step level.

Comment: Created an edit to illustrate passing only the boolean result of a secret-check which can be used in the GitHub Actions `jobs.<job_id>.if` (or jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].if) conditional expression.  This maintains the secrets context as intended